# JPanel Graphics not drawing anything (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm having trouble getting the graphics of my JPanel to work. It refuses to draw anything, regardless of anything I've tried and anything I can find on the internet.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Mandelbrot{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame win=new JFrame();
        JPanel dis=new JPanel();
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setResizable(false);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.add(dis);
        dis.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,500));
        win.pack();
        Graphics g=dis.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code can compile?

Comment: You need to override the paint method for the JPanel.

Comment: sorifiend I don't know what that means or how to do it

Comment: @jjohnn91 See this link for an official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html (Click next at the bottom to go through the lessons). Specifically this lesson will be most helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html note how the jpanel needs to be extended, and then you do your custom painting inside this method `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: If you want a simple answer, then use a Canvas instead of a JPanel to do your painting.

Comment: @sorifiend Do you mean:  JPanel dis=new JPanel(){ protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){ [painting code] }}; ?

Comment: If so, I've already tried this, but its useless to me if I can't go back to paintComponent later in the program and add new things to it defined by variables yet to be created.

Comment: @jjohnn91 If you need to be constantly changing things, then a JPanel is probably not your best option. However, one hack that you can do is to make the JPanel draw a buffered image. Then you can directly edit and draw to the buffered image every time you need to make a change. I recommend you rethink what you are trying to do because you can probably just paint to a bunch of different labels/glass panes and overlay them however you want, this will allow you to have moving components/animations in a foreground item, and make different changes to the background item.

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer because I ran out of comment room:

**Note:**
If you need to be constantly changing things, then a JPanel is probably not your best option. I recommend you rethink what you are trying to do because you should probably use a Canvas or paint to a bunch of different labels/glass panes and overlay them however you want, this will allow you to have moving components/animations in a foreground item, and make different changes to the background item.

Alternatively, you can make the JPanel draw a buffered image, or you can store a list of items to paint, and you can paint them each time. For the buffered image method you can directly edit and draw to the buffered image every time you need to make a change.

---

Below is an example of how to use the buffered image method.

First create a custom JPanel in a new class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(panelWidth, panelHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Draw the canvas
        g.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Now in your main method you can replace `JPanel dis=new JPanel()` with this:

```
DrawPanel dis = new DrawPanel();

Graphics g=dis.canvas.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Note how I use `dis.canvas` to get the graphics of the bufferedImage instead of the graphics of the JPanel.

It's as simple as that.

As per Andrews comment. You should consider extending a JLabel instead of a JPanel, it is much more lightweight, and easier to update using `label.repaint();`.

Comment: @jjohnn91 Updated the code to properly show how `dis.canvas.getGraphics();`

Comment: Note that when using a `BufferedImage` as the canvas, we can display it in a `JLabel`. When the image changes, simply call `label.repaint();` and the changes will appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    };
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}
```

Just an example - you should create a new Class subclassing JPanel, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: This is close, but I've tried this. I need to be able to add lines of painting code (e.g, g.fillRect(0,0,10,10);) anywhere in the program because of the nature of what I'm trying to make. When I've tried doing this before the things I try to paint simply don't appear.

Comment: Additionally, What does super.paint(g); do? What is super?

Comment: WARNING: Do not override the paint method, you should only override the `paintComponent` method when working with swing. The only time you should override `paint` is when working with pure AWT components only.

Comment: @sorifiend How can I over ride the paintComponent method and still be able to call add new lines of paint code from anywhere in the program? I need to be able to simply write dis.getGraphics().fillRect(0,0,10,10); and just have it, well, work. Anywhere. How can I do this?